# NetLogo: break out of nested foreach loop

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I'm trying to break out of a nested foreach loop using 2 lists of sorted turtles.
But instead of just leaving the inner loop, netlogo breaks out of the whole procedure.
I have a code like the one below (this one is made up, but has exactly the same structure):

```
to do-something    
  let xturtles sort-by [ [a b] -> [birthday] of a > [birthday] of b ] turtles
  ;; construct an ordered set
  foreach xturtles [ the-xturtle ->
    ask the-xturtle [
      let xage birthday
      let yturtles sort-by [ [a b] -> [birthday] of a > [birthday] of b ] turtles with [birthday < xage] 
       ;; construct a second ordered set
      foreach yturtles [ the-yturtle ->
        let breakout-condition? false
        ask the-yturtle [
          if (hidden? ) [
            set breakout-condition? true
          ]
        ]
        if breakout-condition? [ stop ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

However, when the stop condition is reached, netlogo breaks out of the whole procedure, instead of continuing with the outer loop (the xturtles loop)?

Is that the expected behavior? If so, what is a good practice in this case?

Thanks!
Felix

Answer (score 3):

It looks even nesting the `stop` within an extra `ask` procedure in the same procedure doesn't help. However, if you need a quick fix I think you can replace the second `foreach` loop with a standalone procedure that contains the `stop` as a workaround. For example, this procedure follows a similar format to yours and the same problem comes up- as soon as `stop` is called the broader `foreach` is exited.

```
to nest-foreach-example
  ca
  crt 1
  let xs [ 1 2 3 4 ]
  let ys [ 1 2 3 4 ]
  foreach xs [ 
    x ->
    foreach ys [ 
      y ->
      ask turtles [
        if y > x [
          stop
        ]
      ]
      print word x y 
    ]
  ]
end
```

This prints out `11`.

However, if you make a custom procedure to take the place of your "y" `foreach` loop, it works (with or without the `ask turtles`):

```
to nest-foreach-example-turtles
  ca
  crt 1
  let xs [ 1 2 3 4 ]
  let ys [ 1 2 3 4 ]
  foreach xs [ 
    x ->
    for-y x ys 
  ]

end

to for-y [ x_ ys ]
  foreach ys [
    y ->
    ask turtles [
      if y > x_ [
        stop
      ]
    ]
    print word x_ y
  ]
end
```

Outputs:

```
11
21
22
31
32
33
41
42
43
44
```

Comment: Thanks Luke! Yes, that's an option. Maybe I can come up with a general reporter to be used whenever this kind of computation is used. 
Another option I found is to use a stop flag and inside the inner loop to check if it's body should be executed. But this adds an extra variable and the loop is running anyway.

Comment: @FelixHelix - You bet! You may be able to figure this out, but I'm not sure how to go more general than the `for-y` example already is, as it accepts the current item being iterated and the new list you want to pass to it. It should be "nestable" as is, too. You're right about the stop flag, but honestly if you don't have a very large model I bet you're probably okay to let the loop run. If you have a larger one, something like the `for-y` will save some computation time.